# O que significa _: e _

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

O que significa  _: e _. na definição de funções como no exemplo abaixo.

```
constructor(){
  router.events.subscribe((_:NavigationEnd) => this.currentUrl = _.url);
}
```

tenho muitas duvidas a respeito.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O underscore (`_`) é uma variável. O ponto após ele significa que ele é um objeto e está sendo acessado uma das suas propriedades

```js
let _ = {
  foo: 'bar',
  baz: v => `foo bar baz ${v}`
}

console.log(_)
console.log(_.foo)
console.log(_.baz('taz'))
```

Como citado nos comentários por @HebertdeLima, o Underscore.js usa esse carácter como um "objeto pai" contendo as funções e valores da biblioteca

O underscore também **costuma** (é uma convenção, não uma obrigação) ser usado para propriedades e funções privadas de um objeto:

```js
function Foo(_bar) {
  this.setBar = (bar) => { _bar = bar  }
  this.getBar = ()    => { return _bar }
}

let baz = new Foo('taz')
console.log(baz._bar)
console.log(baz.getBar())
```

No TypeScript, o dois pontos (`:`) indica a que tipo essa variável deve ser:

```
let foo :string //Tipo string

interface Baz {
  let taz :boolean; //Baz é um objeto com uma propriedade taz, do tipo booleana
}

let bar :Baz //Tipo Baz
```

Comment: **costuma ser usado para propriedades e funções privadas de um objeto**. Acho que seria interessante salientar que o `_` em funções privadas não é uma nomenclatura padrão, e nem uma obrigação, é somente uma convenção que **algumas** pessoas utilizam, e que cada dia mais está sendo adotada

Comment: Sim, como disse, **costuma**, mais os frameworks e bibliotecas que fazem isso, editei a pergunta reforçando essa ideia, valeu pela dica @MarceloBoni